# Facebook appends #.VUQQmn_6E7E.facebook to my url when clicked from facebook

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm not worried about the extra syntax that gets added to the url when clicked on from facebook, I'm worried about the javascript breaking on the page.

I get this in the console: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #.VUQQmn_6E7E.facebook

and it breaks all the javascript. The page works fine when it doesn't get #.VUQQmn_6E7E.facebook added to the url.

Comment: These are tracking parameters added by Facebook. If those make your scripts break, then you will have to fix your scripts.